# Can I reuse same DataTable object within same windows form?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to c#. I am using windows forms and I read/write data from/to sql database. In my application I reuse the connection string (in app.config file) and sqlCommand multiple times and there is no problem.

As shown below in my code, I use a DataTable object. Can I reuse the same DataTable object (MyDataTable) multiple times within same form? And what is the best practice of doing that? Thank you.

```
 MyConnection.Open();
 SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table_Price");

 cm.Connection = MyConnection;

 SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
 DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();
 DataAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable);
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Just assign the instance to a (class scope) variable.

Comment: Can we close it now?

Comment: Yes, but how? @Tim We don't have a 'too basic' close reason.

Comment: It depends. If you use your data table to bind something, then it is not a good idea.

Comment: Why not, data binding works perfect this way. @erikscandola

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter. as I said I am new to c# . so if you consider yourself as a professional in C# or sql, keep in mind there are many of us who still learning.... and if you don't have an answer to my question then there is no need of a such useless comment.

Comment: Maybe you will understand Tim if you are a regular user here and have such questions 100 times a day...

Comment: Maybe I wrong but it's possible that when you change values in your data table also the binding elements change because use the same reference.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: it's not too basic but too broad. Of course you can access an object in a whole class. If OP would show a situation where it seems to be impossible we could help.

Comment: That is a feature, right? @erikscandola

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry I'm not english, what do you mean?

Comment: That (often) it is intended that the same row updates in two screens at the same time due to data binding. @erikscandola

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes. This can happen, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I tried with a listbox, i binding it with list of object and then I changed a value in list and in listbox values have changed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the instance to a class variable (I put your original code in a method to make clear how it works):

```
private DataTable myDataTable; // create a class scoped variable

private void X()
{
    MyConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table_Price");

    cm.Connection = MyConnection;

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    this.myDataTable = new DataTable(); // assign it here
    DataAdapter.Fill(this.myDataTable);
}

private void Y()
{
    // reuse this.myDataTable here
}
```

Please read up on classes and class members on MSDN:

- [Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)
- [Abstract and Sealed Classes and Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx)

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman. if I want to reuse the DataTable then I have to delete all the data on it before I use it again. any idea how to do that? thank you

Comment: Why would you? Then just create a new object. If you intend to trash it before you reuse it, then just create a new object.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman . obviously because I want to reuse it again, and if you don't clear all the data in datatable before using it again  then it will mix up with the previous data ( because the data still in datatable ).

Answer (score 0):

many times when using a DataTable say in a forms project one would set the DataTable as the DataSource of a DataGridView e.g. dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable. Later we want to access the data source so we would cast the DataSource to a DataTable or have a language extension method e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace demo
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static DataTable DataTable(this DataGridView sender)
        {
            return ((DataTable)sender.DataSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's use it

```
var demo = dataGridView1.DataTable()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("LastName") == "Payne")
    .Select(row => row).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or perhaps use AsEnumerable in the extension

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DataTable DataTable(this DataGridView sender)
    {
        return ((DataTable)sender.DataSource);
    }
    public static EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> DataTableEnumerable(this DataGridView sender)
    {
        return ((DataTable)sender.DataSource).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Of course if not working in this manner we would use something like Patrick Hofman suggested.

Here is a [working example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!880&authkey=!AMw260fQVnO7L8c&ithint=file%2Czip) in VS2013 but rather than against a DataGridView I am going to a BindingSource, set the DataSource to a DataTable then the BindingSource becomes the data source of the DataGridView so the extension method is now for the BindingSource.

```
public static DataTable DataTable(this BindingSource sender)
{
    return ((DataTable)sender.DataSource);
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that is a little too complicated for our OP? Just saving a class member to extension methods?

Comment: Perhaps Patrick but this is how developers learn. I added an example which is a modified version of a MSDN code sample I did. Original code sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-bff5eaaf

Comment: @Karen Payne.   @ Karen Payne.  if I want to reuse the DataTable then I have to delete all the data on it before I use it again, right?. any idea how to do that? thank you

Comment: No necessarily, there is always DataTable.Rows.Clear which removes rows, DataTable.Coumns.Clear to clear columns. Of course dependent on the state of the data you can add/remove columns etc. You can re-create the data table as I am doing in this code (my MSDN code sample) https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-stored-procedures-1384f04c/sourcecode?fileId=147002&pathId=1727765905